# Search form in Google App Engine with Mako Template

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, mako

The script is in data.py and template file is search.mako. The search form is in MainPage method (not included in the code below). I enter the search term but nothing happens. Can you help understand what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```
class Pet(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Search(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        query = Pet.all()
        results = self.request.get('searchquery')
        q = query.filter('name =', 'results')

        template_values = {'q': q,}

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'search.mako')
        templ = Template(filename=path)
        self.response.out.write(templ.render(**template_values))
```

And this is the search.mako

```
<html>
<body>

% for cat in q:
  <p>${cat.name}</p>
% endfor  

</html>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding fetch() fixed the problem:

```
class Search(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        query = Pet.all()
        q = query.filter('name =', self.request.get('searchquery')).fetch(10)
```